# R: Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r

I have written a userdefined function:

```
epf <- function(z,x,noise=std_noise){
    z_dims <- length(z)
    std_noise <- 0.5*matrix(1,1,z_dims)
    std_noise <- as.data.frame(std_noise)

    obs_prob <- dnorm(z,x[1:z_dims],noise)

    error <- prod(cbind(1,obs_prob))
    return(error)
}
```

This function is called in a for-loop in another function:

```
w <- matrix(0,N,1)
        for (i in 1:N){
            w[i] <- epf(z,p[i,],R_noise) 
        }
```

where `z` is a 2-dimensional vector, `N=1000`,  `p` is a dataframe of 1000 observations and 4 variables and `R_noise` is a dataframe og 1 observation and 4 variables.

Here I get the error: "Non-numeric argument to mathematical function", for the line `obs_prob <- dnorm(z,x[1:z_dims],noise)`

Can anyone help me with finding the error?

I have looked through questions similar to mine, but I still can't find the error in my code.

Edit:
Added definition of `N`

Comment: `'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: num 1.44
 $ V2: num -2.66
NULL`

Comment: that's the problem. `dnorm` will accept a matrix, not a data frame. try `dnorm(as.matrix(z), x[1...`

Comment: @plafort better to put this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dnorm(as.matrix(z), x[1:a_dims], noise)` may work better.

And more broadly speaking, a data frame with one row and two columns may be better expressed as a vector. Data frames look like matrices and as you put it 'two-dimensional vectors', but they are different in important aspects.

The same error may be occurring because you are feeding `dnorm` a second data frame in its last argument `noise` by passing `R_noise`.

Also, consider that `p[i, ]` has four values. It is being subsetted by `obs_prob` with `x[1:z_dims]`. In this case, `z_dims` will equal 2 since `length(z)` is 2. So you are evaluating `dnorm(data.frame(z), p[1, ][1:2], data.frame(R_noise))`.

Comment: I still get the same error. I will try to look through my code again, and see if the error is to be found in one of the other arguments.

Comment: I changed them all arguments in the loop to matrices. It worked - thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. Take note that different values are being recycled in your second argument of `dnorm`. Check the results with a small example to inspect accuracy.